# primefaces 3.5 selectOneMenu. Error:Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: validation, jsf, netbeans, primefaces

I want to update selectOneMenu (d2) with another(d1) than the d2 componoent should update message box. Everything is ok but when i try to use selectOneMenu (d2) with updated values it causes error:"form:d2: Validation Error: Value is not valid".

what is funny when i add "editable = "true" to selectOneMenu(d2) everything works fine.

My page:

```
<h:form id="form">  
                <p:growl id="msgs" /> 

                <p:selectOneMenu id="d1" value="#{jSFManagedBean.d1SelectedItem}" effect="fold"   
                                  filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select one" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{jSFManagedBean.d1ItemList}" />  
                    <f:ajax event="change"    listener="#{jSFManagedBean.generateD2List()}" render="d2" />  
                </p:selectOneMenu>    


                <p:selectOneMenu id="d2" value="#{jSFManagedBean.d2SelectedItem}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select one1" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{jSFManagedBean.d2ItemList}" /> 
                    <f:ajax event="change"    listener="#{jSFManagedBean.addInfo()}" render="msgs" />  

                </p:selectOneMenu> 

</h:form>
```

jSFManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class JSFManagedBean 
{
    public void addInfo() 
    {  
        System.out.println("Add Info D1: " +  D1SelectedItem + "  D2: " + D2SelectedItem );
    }
    ....
}
```

d1ItemList creaded in:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    System.out.println("INIT");
     if (dana1Facade.findAll().size() < 1)
     {
                 for (int i = 0 ; i < 10  ; i ++)
        {
            Entities.Dana1 d1 = new Entities.Dana1();
            //d1.setId(1l);
            d1.setPozycja("Pozycja " + i);
            dana1Facade.create(d1);
        }
     }
....
}
```

d2ItemList created in:

```
public void generateD2List()
{   
    d2ItemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    d2ItemList = dana2Facade.getDana2Pozycja(Integer.parseInt(D1SelectedItem.substring(0, 1)));//Integer.parseInt(D1SelectedItem.substring(0, 1))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
 <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{jSFManagedBean.generateD2List()}"
    render="d2" />
```

to

```
 <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{jSFManagedBean.generateD2List()}"
    update="d2" />
```

see if that helps.

Comment: update is in primefaces(<p:) i use this <f: with update but its not matter what i use its work the same.